# get azure subscription belongs to what type for example Pay As you Go, MCA, EA, CSP

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-billing-api

I tried to fetch azure subscription belongs to what type for example Pay As you Go, MCA, EA, CSP by using REST API But I am not able to find the appropriate API for this case.
I used Consumption Usage Details API, from this API response I am getting **kind** as **Legacy** or **Modern**

Is there any Rest API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the Offer Types from any API's, But you can get the `offerId` from the [Consumption Usage Details API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usage-details/list).

So, After you get offerId (for example `"offerId" : "MS-AZR-0003P"`) , then you can take just the offerId number (i.e. `0003P`). And refer it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/legal/offer-details/) to check what type of Offer it is (in this case its `Pay-As-You-Go`).